# Language Translation API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, google-api

I want to implement language translation feature in my iPhone app,
is there any API which is free that I can use, or any other way to do this.

Comment: do you know to retrieve it from JSON?

Comment: **Find my post here ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043449/enable-to-type-in-other-language/9043536#9043536 And from [google](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Google's [Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) is not free anymore.

So, If you want to use a free language translation API, here are some links:

- Mygengo Translation API:        http://mygengo.com/api/
- Microsoft Translator APIs:      http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/
- Speaklite Translate API:        http://www.speaklike.com/access-professional-translation-via-api/
- WebServiceX Translate API:      http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63

This is also helpful:

http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2011/07/03/objective-c-wrap-over-microsoft-bing-translate-api/

Comment: What can you say about quality of those translators?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Yandex's Translate API](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/). It's free and its structure is almost identical to [Google's](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/).

I've only just started playing around with it but the reviews I've seen are all fairly positive. It has three straightforward endpoints, similar to Google 's: `/detect`, `/translate`, and `/getLangs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FGTranslator](https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator) for both Google and Bing translation in iOS.

Comment: This looks like your own project, can you update this to disclaim that it is your own?