# Convert image Text into other languages in IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can i convert Image text like English,Spanish,French into other languages(Hindi,Spanish, Japanese, Chinese ets) in IPhone/IPAD ?
iS it possible or not??
Example:- [image]

can i convert this image text into other languages, any API or Webservices is available or not??

Comment: it's not possible to convert image text to other language..!,because that is image only not a characters...!

Comment: I want to fetch text data from images then convert into other languages,then we can put that text into that image again,but i dont know How can i implement this logic?

Comment: you can't fetch text data from image,because,images are contains rgb values only...!

Comment: This is really two questions: how do you extract text from an image, which is covered by the question sky1224 links to: [Getting text from image on ios (image processing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing), and machine translation, which is covered by [Language Translation API for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732633/language-translation-api-for-iphone)

Comment: Did you get the answer, if yes then please share i am also working on same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the text with the OCR engines.

[Getting text from image on ios (image processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing)

And then you can translate the text from a language to any other. Maybe it's fully possible with the Google translator engine for iOS. It's free, but free translator is inconvinient for the user and the good app. You'd better purchase it and integrate it, then your app can work well...

But I'm afraid your image texts size are different...