# Runtime Language Translation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

There is a app that I am trying to build for which I need to implement language translation. Now here the data is being fetched from a server in realtime, so I cannot use xcode's default localisation.

I know there is a Google Translate api, which I am trying to avoid for now because they are charging some $20 or something. The app will be free so I dont plan to shell out extra money. Are there some other options? I tried hacking the translator.php code (http://code.google.com/p/php-google-translator/), but again Google have put in lot of restrictions. Please help.

Comment: This post might be useful for you:-
 <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732633/language-translation-api-for-iphone>

Answer (score 0):

This is to let you know that I have found a solution and pity it escaped under my nose. The Solution comes from Microsoft - Bing Translator.

https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator#schema

As of now you can use 2million characters for free per month.

(PS - If you have the resources go for Google Translator api, the difference & accuracy is evident)

Answer (score 0):

Google Translation API is not free now. if you want use check it out at http://github.com/xhan/PLTranslator (It's example of google translater)

So, If you want to use Free Language Translation API, then here is Some link:

Mygengo Translation API: http://mygengo.com/api/

Microsoft Translator APIs: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/

Speaklite Translate API: http://www.speaklike.com/access-professional-translation-via-api/

WebServiceX Translate API: http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63