# iOS- How to translate english (.string file) language in different languages at a time?

Tags: ios, localization, translate, language-translation

I am facing a problem. I am working on an app which is supported around 30 languages. I have tried google toolkit translate (https://translate.google.com/toolkit/ ) but it is not working properly. For example let assume in .string file I have 40 lines of codes. If I translate language using google toolkit then it converts just 4-7 lines sometimes 8-9 times and so on. Others all lines it skips. Please let me know how can we translate English language in multiple language (around 30)  at a time. Please  share Any tool name or site name. Thanks guys.

Comment: have a look at [localization manager](https://github.com/LightweightInTouch/iOSLocalizationManager). Also, google translate has [API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/)

Comment: why can't you manually keep 30 languages 30 strings files separately? Google will never give you exact translation...

Comment: @  Fahim Parkar, Please read question carefully, I don't know how a English word written in different languages. For example : "image selected successfully" how to write  this English string in other 30 languages.

Comment: Fahim asks a valid question. The 'normal' solution is to use the provided localisation features to replace all such strings with placeholders and then get a professional translator to add all your required translations. If you use an automated tool it will be web based so will be slow, need Internet access and give poor quality 'machine' translations.

Comment: @Ali Beadle  and  Fahim Parkar, May you please share  professional translator tool name by which I can translate English language to other (around in 30 languages ). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Monusingh When I say 'Professional Translator' I mean a person or organisation. Automated tools will give poor results, but if that is what you want Google Translate is as good as any I know. Have you followed gaussblurinc's link to its API?

Comment: Let me check both options 1st : gaussblurinc's link to its API and Google Translate, and then I can decide best option for my requirement. and I don't want use a person or organisation to complete this task , I want to do it myself, Thanks

Comment: @Monusingh: if you speak any language other than English I would recommend that you try machine translation (google translate, bing translate, freetranslation.com, whatever) for that language. If the quality for your language is good then use if for other languages, too. But if it is bad, how can you be sure it will be better for those of your 30 target languages that you do not speak?

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a project which can convert your localization.strings file to any language using google translation api.**

You just need to copy paste all the data of localization.string file into a txt file. and add that txt file in app bundle file and specify file name in Constants.h file. Also mention the google translator api key. You can also mail the translated file.

[Localization using google transtion iOS Project Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-WC_LfXKrhZTHFwdThoX2tlNG8)